# s3cmd not working as cron-task when echos/dates are added

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron, cron-task, s3cmd

I have a Digital Ocean Droplet (VPS) running Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) and am able to run a sync successfully with this command:

```
s3cmd sync --recursive --preserve /srv s3://MY-BUCKET-NAME
```

And if I put that same command in to a .sh to run as a cron-task every minute, it works:

```
* * * * * sh /srv/backupToS3.sh >> /srv/backupToS3.log
```

But when I add some echos and dates to the .sh:

```
echo 'Started:'
date +'%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
s3cmd sync --recursive --preserve /srv s3://MY-BUCKET-NAME
echo 'Finished:'
date +'%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

the s3cmd sync does not work/run anymore. But the echos and dates print to the log file:

```
Started:
Mon Jun  8 17:45:01 PDT 2015
Finished:
Mon Jun  8 17:45:01 PDT 2015
```

Any help or push in the right direction would be very appreciated. I originally followed [this article](https://levels.io/backup-linode-digital-ocean-vps-amazon-s3/) to get this far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

s3cmd uses a configuration file located at ~/.s3cfg. It's probably having trouble picking that up. Pass in `--config=/home/username/.s3cfg` and see if that helps.

In any case, s3cmd isn't consistently maintained. The official commandline client (aws-cli) is much better in many ways.

---

edit: use this as your .sh file, make sure it has the executable bit set (`chmod 755 whatever.sh`).

```
echo 'Started:'
date +'%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
/usr/bin/s3cmd sync --recursive --preserve --config=/usr/bin/s3cmd --verbose /srv s3://MY-BUCKET-NAME
echo 'Finished:'
date +'%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

Comment: You're the 2nd person I've seen mention AWS-CLI over s3cmd (1st was in a similar question about cron-task), perhaps I will look in to that. I do not see a .s3cfg file in my home directory (I'm SFTPed in to droplet via Cyberduck, showing hidden files). /home is empty.

Comment: Also, the command runs fine alone (w/o the echo and date lines) wouldn't that mean that s3cmd is working fine?

Comment: If you don't have a .s3cfg, where is s3cmd reading your IAM keys from?

Comment: Ah, found it with a find command: `find / -name .s3cfg`, it is in `/root/.s3cfg`. What is your take on my other question/comment, though? Would it not be that the s3cmd is working fine since its runs w/o the echo and date lines?

Comment: To confirm...should I be putting `--config=/root/.s3cfg`? and is that to go in the sm3cmd line? ie:  `s3cmd sync --recursive --preserve --config=/root/.s3cfg /srv s3://MY-BUCKET-NAME`

Comment: yeah, try that. you haven't given all the information necessary to confirm- for instance, is that cron in root's crontab?

Comment: Yes, the cron is in the root's crontab.

Comment: No change with `s3cmd sync --recursive --preserve --config=/root/.s3cfg /srv s3://MY-BUCKET-NAME`...still just the echos and dates in the log file and the sync does not run.

Comment: put the full path to s3cmd (use `which s3cmd` to find it), and add `--verbose`.

Comment: running `which s3cmd` returns `/usr/bin/s3cmd`. Do you mean for me to add that path in the config section from before? And is `--verbose` okay to add anywhere in the line? ie: `s3cmd sync --recursive --preserve --config=/usr/bin/s3cmd --verbose /srv s3://MY-BUCKET-NAME`

Comment: I think you mean for the `config=` to be `config=/root/.s3cfg`? It tried it how you have it and received ignore errors. Changing it produces same result: echo and date lines print to .log, but sync does not run. I did the `chmod` as well.

Comment: yeah, I meant for it to be .s3cfg, I just copied your line- oops. Anyhow, if you aren't getting anything, there's something more going on that is missing.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. I will look in to learning aws-cli.

Comment: Thanks alot! Been struggeling for two days now getting s3cmd running from cron in Centos. 

ERROR: /.s3cfg: No such file or directory
ERROR: Configuration file not available.
ERROR: Consider using --configure parameter to create one

--config=/path/to/.s3cfg     worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and i tried to figure out why it is not running. My solution was to add the following lines to the top of my script:

`export HOME=/home/$USERNAME
cd /home/$USERNAME`

Also you should call the s3cmd with:

```
/usr/bin/s3cmd
```

OR put the following line to the top of your script:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```